# "Enquire from someone" vs "enquire with someone"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which is the correct sentence from these two?

> 1. Can you enquire from her?
> 2. Can you enquire with her?

I tried to search the internet but most results talk about the difference between *enquire* and *inquire*.

Comment: I'd add (3) "Can you enquire of her...?" where the ellipsis represents the actual question: "Can you enquire of her whether you need to go?" Also, ***ask*** is usually better than *enquire* followed by a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "enquire of" is the correct usage.
See this: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/enquire-of